# File browser component for Java swing

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, file-browser

Has anyone come across a fully customizable (compatible with all standard LnF), fast file browser component for Java Swing ?

I should be able to place this component to Netbeans UI palette and drag and drop in to any JPanel while designing the UI. Also it should support directory, single file, multiple file selection along with file type filtering.
There must be something because I have seen this in applications like jEdit etc.

Note that I am not asking about a dialog box like JFileChooser instead a browser/explorer/tree-view like component.

Comment: See also [File Browser GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Wondering why there is no stand-alone component though!

Comment: Looks like there is no such component for Swing right now. Will have to build from scratch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple file system browser built in a `JPanel`:

- [File Tree](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm)

Here are a few more complex examples of a file browser with icons, popup menus, and tooltips.
These are all built in a `JFrame`:

- [File Tree with Icons](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FilefolderTreewithicons.htm)
- [File Tree with Popup Menu](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTreewithPopupMenu.htm)
- [File Tree with Tooltips](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTreewithTooltips.htm)

These examples probably aren't as customizable as you may want, but they're a pretty good
starting point for adding new functionality.

For further reading, [Swing, Second Edition](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Manning-Java-Swing.html) (Chapter 17) walks through implementing a `JTree` component for browsing your file system complete with lazy loading, custom renders, popup menus, and tooltips.
If you'd like to see just the source, you can get it [here](http://www.manning-source.com/books/robinson2/swing2e.zip).

There is also the **FileBro** that you may want to take a look at. Perhaps you can use it, or at least borrow implementation details.

- [FileBro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui?noredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks for the references, but these are not what I am looking for. I was expecting to see a full blown UI component.

Answer (score 2):

see DJ Project:
http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html

Comment: I am not looking for a "web browser", I need a file browser component - simple and self contained.

Comment: download the example and try it, there are different type of file browsers.