# Explorer Panel in Java

Tags: java, panel, explorer, integrate

does anyone know a free windows explorer type of project written in java?
Basically i just want to implement a simple windows explorer but dont want to start from scratch with all the drag and drops, icon arrangements and so on.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [File browser component for Java swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195495/file-browser-component-for-java-swing)

Comment: I dont think there is one actually. There are very good full blown utilities that are fully developed which act as windows explorer replacements or add ons .. take a look at ultraexplorer and explorer ++. I personally love ultraexplorer and use that instead of the windows explorer. But I dont think they are java projects though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, that was almost what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can explore common navigator framework for eclipse, it would use swt, jface, draw2d. It provides with drag and drop options.