# Java JFrame adding browse button with field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

How do I create in Java a GUI to allow a user to enter a directory into a text field and have a browse button next to it, so they can chose the folder easier? I need to do this using JComponents hopefully. Like the last entry shown here: http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/assets/flashbutton/images/ss5insertdialog.gif

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195495/file-browser-component-for-java-swing) will be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use a JTextField and JFileChooser
You have a demo here : 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.filechooser/CreateDlg.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger a JFileChooser with the button, and then listen to its response to populate the field. Tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). If you don't want people to manually edit the field, set it disabled so that it can't be edited, but does show the text.